# why __builtins__ is both module and dict

Tags: python, python-module, built-in

I am using the built-in module to insert a few instances, so they can be accessed globally for debugging purposes. The problem with the `__builtins__` module is that it is a module in a main script and is a dict in modules, but as my script depending on cases can be a main script or a module, I have to do this:

```
if isinstance(__builtins__, dict):
    __builtins__['g_frame'] = 'xxx'
else:
    setattr(__builtins__, 'g_frame', 'xxx')
```

Is there a workaround, shorter than this? More importantly, why does `__builtins__` behave this way?

Here is a script to see this. Create a module a.py:

```
#module-a
import b
print 'a-builtin:',type(__builtins__)
```

Create a module b.py:

```
#module-b
print 'b-builtin:',type(__builtins__)
```

Now run python a.py:

```
$ python a.py 
b-builtin: <type 'dict'>
a-builtin: <type 'module'>
```

Comment: For more info, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11181519/python-whats-the-difference-between-builtin-and-builtins

[Possible Duplicate]

Comment: did you try using `import builtins` instead? What results did it give you? I used that as suggested here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61084916/how-does-one-make-an-already-opened-file-readable-e-g-sys-stdout/61087617#61087617) and it seems to work.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think you want the `__builtin__` module (note the singular).

See the docs:

> [27.3. `__builtin__` — Built-in objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__builtin__.html)
>
> **CPython implementation detail:** Most modules have the name `__builtins__` (note the `'s'`) made available as part of their globals. The value of `__builtins__` is normally either this module or the value of this modules’s [sic] **`__dict__`** attribute. Since this is an implementation detail, it may not be used by alternate implementations of Python.

Comment: What about Python3? `NameError: name '__builtin__' is not defined`

Comment: @warvariuc: the module was renamed to [`builtins`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html).

Comment: can you answer the title of the question? is `__builtins__` a dict or not? and when is it one or the other? The small details of the OP aren't as relevant as the searchable title given by search engines. Please answer that.