# Stubbing IO in nosetests

Tags: python, nosetests

I'm currently trying to migrate a test suite to use nosetests. I can't find this in the docs, but is there anyway that you can stub I/O operations with nosetests? What is a simple example for stubbing I/O?

```
Example:

def test_1():
  read_from_file

def stub_1():
  return "file content"
```

Reference: 
https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: May be you are asking about mocking python's `open` function (like it was done [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237693/mocking-openfile-name-in-unit-tests))?