# mock open for unit testing in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-mock

I would like to test, using unittest, a method which reads from a file using a context manager:

```
with open(k_file, 'r') as content_file:
    content = content_file.read()
```

I don't want to have to create a file on my system so I wanted to mock it, but I'm not suceeding much at the moment. I've found [mock_open](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/helpers.html#mock-open) but I don't really understand how I'm supposed to use it and feed the mock as content_file in my test case. There is for instance this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19663055/914086) here, but I do not understand how one is supposed to write this in a test case without modifying the original code.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`mock_open()` is the way to go; you patch `open` in your code-under-test with the result of a `mock_open()` call:

```
mocked_open = unittest.mock.mock_open(read_data='file contents\nas needed\n')
with unittest.mock.patch('yourmodule.open', mocked_open, create=True):
    # tests calling your code; the open function will use the mocked_open object
```

The [`patch()` context manager](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html#patch) will put a `open()` global into your module (I named it `yourmodule`), bound to the `mocked_open()`-produced object. This object will pretend to produce a file object when called.

The only thing this mock file object *won't* do yet is iteration; you cannot do `for line in content_file` with it, at least not in current versions of the `mock` library. See [Customizing unittest.mock.mock_open for iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24779893/customizing-unittest-mock-mock-open-for-iteration) for a work-around.

Comment: Thank you! I did not understand where to call my module, but now it works.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is [pyfakefs](http://github.com/jmcgeheeiv/pyfakefs).  It allows you to create a fake file system, write and read files, set permissions and more without ever touching your real disk.  It also contains a practical example and tutorial showing how to apply pyfakefs to both unittest and doctest.