# In python, how to write unit test for a function is using with open file?

Tags: python, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

This is function to get version and using with open to read file from file path location.

```
def get_version(self):
    try:
        with open("file_path") as openfile:
            for line in openfile:
                sline = line.split()
                for row, column in enumerate(sline):
                    if column == "version=":
                        version = sline[row+1].strip('"')
    return version
```

Comment: And also this is only a part of your function because I don't see `except` block.

Comment: Hi @sid, and welcome! It looks like there are a few similar questions, about unit testing builtin functions such as `open()`. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5237693/222529) as a starting point.

Comment: except block is handled in UT part

Answer (score 6):

You can use [unittest.mock.mock_open(mock=None, read_data=None)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#mock-open) to mock the `open` function.

E.g.

`main.py`:

```py
class MyClass:
    def get_version(self):
        version = ''
        with open("file_path") as openfile:
            for line in openfile:
                sline = line.split()
                for row, column in enumerate(sline):
                    if column == "version=":
                        version = sline[row+1].strip('"')

        return version
```

`test_main.py`:

```py
from main import MyClass
import unittest
from unittest.mock import mock_open, patch


class TestMain(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_get_version(self):
        m = mock_open(read_data='version= 1.0.0')
        with patch('builtins.open', m) as mocked_open:
            myclass_instace = MyClass()
            version = myclass_instace.get_version()
            self.assertEqual(version, '1.0.0')
            m.assert_called_with('file_path')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

unit test results with 100% coverage:

```sh
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.011s

OK
Name                                      Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
src/stackoverflow/60183706/main.py           10      0   100%
src/stackoverflow/60183706/test_main.py      14      0   100%
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                        24      0   100%
```

Python version: `Python 3.7.5`

Comment: I have used your answer with Python 3.6, but it doesn't work perfectly may be  because `read_data` doesn't work with `readline()`. So I have written an other answer where I have added methods `__iter__` and `__next__` to the mock object obtains by `mock_open`. However I have upvoted your answer because it has been very useful for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mock_open` helper function:

> unittest.mock.mock_open(mock=None, read_data=None)
>
> A helper function to create a mock to replace the use of open(). It works for open() called directly or used as a context manager.

Previous sentences come from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#mock-open) of the module `unittest.mock`

Because the production method `get_version()` reads a file by a for loop you have to define methods `__iter__` and `__next__` for the mock object instantiated by `mock_open` as suggested by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24779893/customizing-unittest-mock-mock-open-for-iteration/24779923#24779923).

So if your production code is stored in the file `my_class.py` as below:

```
class MyClass:
    def get_version(self):
        version = ''
        with open("file_path") as openfile:
            for line in openfile:
                sline = line.split()
                for row, column in enumerate(sline):
                    if column == "version=":
                        version = sline[row+1].strip('"')
        return version
```

a possible test which uses the helper function `mock_open` could be the following:

```
from my_class import MyClass
import unittest
from unittest.mock import mock_open, patch

class TestMyClass(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_get_version(self):
        # by the argument read_data set the content of the file
        mocked_open = mock_open(read_data='version= 2.1\nsecond line\n')
        EXPECTED_VERSION = "2.1"
        mocked_open_instance = mocked_open.return_value
        mocked_open_instance.__iter__ = lambda self: self
        mocked_open_instance.__next__ = lambda self: next(iter(self.readline, ''))
        with patch('builtins.open', mocked_open):
            sut = MyClass()
            version = sut.get_version()
            self.assertEqual(EXPECTED_VERSION, version)
            mocked_open.assert_called_with('file_path')
            # for the file content 'version= 2.1\nsecond line\n' the readline function must be called 3 times
            self.assertEqual(3, mocked_open_instance.readline.call_count)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Version of Python used is: `Python 3.6`.