# What's the difference between __builtin__ and __builtins__?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, language-design, python-module

I was coding today and noticed something. If I open a new interpreter session (IDLE) and check what's defined with the `dir` function I get this:

```
$ python
>>> dir()
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__']
>>> dir(__builtins__)
['ArithmeticError', 'AssertionError', 'AttributeError', 'BaseException', 'BufferError', 'BytesWarning', 'DeprecationWarning', 'EOFError', 'Ellipsis', 'EnvironmentError', 'Exception', 'False', 'FloatingPointError', 'FutureWarning', 'GeneratorExit', 'IOError', 'ImportError', 'ImportWarning', 'IndentationError', 'IndexError', 'KeyError', 'KeyboardInterrupt', 'LookupError', 'MemoryError', 'NameError', 'None', 'NotImplemented', 'NotImplementedError', 'OSError', 'OverflowError', 'PendingDeprecationWarning', 'ReferenceError', 'RuntimeError', 'RuntimeWarning', 'StandardError', 'StopIteration', 'SyntaxError', 'SyntaxWarning', 'SystemError', 'SystemExit', 'TabError', 'True', 'TypeError', 'UnboundLocalError', 'UnicodeDecodeError', 'UnicodeEncodeError', 'UnicodeError', 'UnicodeTranslateError', 'UnicodeWarning', 'UserWarning', 'ValueError', 'Warning', 'ZeroDivisionError', '_', '__debug__', '__doc__', '__import__', '__name__', '__package__', 'abs', 'all', 'any', 'apply', 'basestring', 'bin', 'bool', 'buffer', 'bytearray', 'bytes', 'callable', 'chr', 'classmethod', 'cmp', 'coerce', 'compile', 'complex', 'copyright', 'credits', 'delattr', 'dict', 'dir', 'divmod', 'enumerate', 'eval', 'execfile', 'exit', 'file', 'filter', 'float', 'format', 'frozenset', 'getattr', 'globals', 'hasattr', 'hash', 'help', 'hex', 'id', 'input', 'int', 'intern', 'isinstance', 'issubclass', 'iter', 'len', 'license', 'list', 'locals', 'long', 'map', 'max', 'memoryview', 'min', 'next', 'object', 'oct', 'open', 'ord', 'pow', 'print', 'property', 'quit', 'range', 'raw_input', 'reduce', 'reload', 'repr', 'reversed', 'round', 'set', 'setattr', 'slice', 'sorted', 'staticmethod', 'str', 'sum', 'super', 'tuple', 'type', 'unichr', 'unicode', 'vars', 'xrange', 'zip']
>>> import __builtin__
['ArithmeticError', 'AssertionError', 'AttributeError', 'BaseException', 'BufferError', 'BytesWarning', 'DeprecationWarning', 'EOFError', 'Ellipsis', 'EnvironmentError', 'Exception', 'False', 'FloatingPointError', 'FutureWarning', 'GeneratorExit', 'IOError', 'ImportError', 'ImportWarning', 'IndentationError', 'IndexError', 'KeyError', 'KeyboardInterrupt', 'LookupError', 'MemoryError', 'NameError', 'None', 'NotImplemented', 'NotImplementedError', 'OSError', 'OverflowError', 'PendingDeprecationWarning', 'ReferenceError', 'RuntimeError', 'RuntimeWarning', 'StandardError', 'StopIteration', 'SyntaxError', 'SyntaxWarning', 'SystemError', 'SystemExit', 'TabError', 'True', 'TypeError', 'UnboundLocalError', 'UnicodeDecodeError', 'UnicodeEncodeError', 'UnicodeError', 'UnicodeTranslateError', 'UnicodeWarning', 'UserWarning', 'ValueError', 'Warning', 'ZeroDivisionError', '_', '__debug__', '__doc__', '__import__', '__name__', '__package__', 'abs', 'all', 'any', 'apply', 'basestring', 'bin', 'bool', 'buffer', 'bytearray', 'bytes', 'callable', 'chr', 'classmethod', 'cmp', 'coerce', 'compile', 'complex', 'copyright', 'credits', 'delattr', 'dict', 'dir', 'divmod', 'enumerate', 'eval', 'execfile', 'exit', 'file', 'filter', 'float', 'format', 'frozenset', 'getattr', 'globals', 'hasattr', 'hash', 'help', 'hex', 'id', 'input', 'int', 'intern', 'isinstance', 'issubclass', 'iter', 'len', 'license', 'list', 'locals', 'long', 'map', 'max', 'memoryview', 'min', 'next', 'object', 'oct', 'open', 'ord', 'pow', 'print', 'property', 'quit', 'range', 'raw_input', 'reduce', 'reload', 'repr', 'reversed', 'round', 'set', 'setattr', 'slice', 'sorted', 'staticmethod', 'str', 'sum', 'super', 'tuple', 'type', 'unichr', 'unicode', 'vars', 'xrange', 'zip']
>>> dir(__builtin__) == dir(__builtins__) # They seem to have the same things
True
```

Please note the last line.

So, my question is:

- Is any an alias of the other one?
- Are the Python guys planning to get rid of one of those?
- What should I use for my own programs?
- What about Python 3?
- Any information is valuable!

**Important:**

I'm using Python 2.7.2+  on Ubuntu.

Comment: as far as my code goes, what seems to work is using `import builtins` see this for an example:  (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61084916/how-does-one-make-an-already-opened-file-readable-e-g-sys-stdout/61087617#61087617)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Straight from the python documentation:
http://docs.python.org/reference/executionmodel.html

> By default, when in the `__main__` module, `__builtins__` is the
>   built-in module `__builtin__` (note: no 's'); when in any other
>   module, `__builtins__` is an alias for the dictionary of the
>   `__builtin__` module itself.
>
> `__builtins__` can be set to a user-created dictionary to create a
>   weak form of restricted execution.
>
> **CPython implementation detail:** Users should not touch `__builtins__`; it is strictly an implementation detail.  Users
>   wanting to override values in the builtins namespace should `import`
>   the `__builtin__` (no 's') module and modify its attributes
>   appropriately. The namespace for a module is automatically created the
>   first time a module is imported.

Note that in Python3, the module `__builtin__` has been renamed to `builtins` to avoid some of this confusion.

Comment: Great answer, thanks a lot. Do you know anything regarding Python 3?

Comment: As other answers have said it's the same for python 3 except the `__builtin__` module is renamed to "builtins" (without underscores). http://docs.python.org/dev/reference/executionmodel.html

Comment: I don't care about the details. What will never make my code have a bug if I use it, modify it, etc?

Answer (score 25):

You should use `__builtin__` in your programs (in the rare cases that you need it), because `__builtins__` is an implementation detail of CPython. It may either be identical to `__builtin__`, or to `__builtin__.__dict__`, depending on the context. As [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/__builtin__.html) says:

> Most modules have the name `__builtins__` (note the 's') made available as part of their globals. The value of `__builtins__` is normally either this module or the value of this modules’s `__dict__` attribute. Since this is an implementation detail, it may not be used by alternate implementations of Python.

In Python 3, `__builtin__` has been renamed to `builtins`, and `__builtins__` remains the same (so you should only use `builtins` in Python 3).

Guido wanted to unite `__builtin__` and `__builtins__`, as you can see [here](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2005-December/058652.html)  ("Having `__builtins__` and `__builtin__` both is clearly a bad idea.") , but apparently nothing came of it.

Apparently the use of `__builtins__` is for performance - it gives direct access to `__builtin__.__dict__` when used in a non-main module, and therefore removes one level of indirection.

Comment: What you mean by "non-main module"? Do you mean modules except ``builtins``?

Comment: using `__builtin__` gives me an error: `NameError: name '__builtin__' is not defined`. What is the right way to access this that doesn't break?

Comment: I believe you're in the `__main__` module is when `__name__ == '__main__'` is `True`.

Answer (score 9):

`__builtin__` is a module containing the built-in functions and types.  The fact that a name `__builtins__` is available containing the same things is an implementation detail.  In other words, if you need to use one of them, do `import __builtin__` and then use `__builtin__`.  See [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/__builtin__.html).

Comment: I don't care about the details. What will never make my code have a bug if I use it, modify it, etc?

Comment: I think what you meant was `import builtins` e.g. see this code https://stackoverflow.com/a/61085162/3167448

Answer (score 2):

You can understand these like following code.
when cpython is started, cpython load `__builtin__` modules into global namespace

import `__builtin__`as `__builtins__`

Comment: @Pinocchio why are you asking spamming this everywhere? maybe if you paid attention to the details or asked for more detail, you would understand why it would or would not cause a bug depending on how you use it.

Answer (score 0):

The `__builtins__` module should not be confused with the `__builtin__` module. The
names, of course, are so similar that it tends to lead to some confusion among new Python
programmers who have gotten this far.
The `__builtins__` module consists of a set of *builtin* names for the *built-ins* namespace. Most, if not all, of these names come from the
`__builtin__` module, which is a module of the built-in functions, exceptions, and other
attributes.
In standard Python execution, `__builtins__` contains all the names from
`__builtin__`. Python used to have a restricted execution model that allowed modification of `__builtins__` where key pieces from `__builtin__` were left out to create a sandbox environment.

However, due its security flaws and the difficulty involved with repairing it,
restricted execution is no longer supported in Python (as of 2.3).