# How to convert object type based on type?

Tags: python, types, instance

I have:

```
x = float(1.0)
y = int(2)

t1 = type(x)
t2 = type(x).__name__
```

If I print `t1` and `t2` I can see the following:

```
print t1
>>> <type 'float'>

print t2
>>> float
```

How can I use `t1` or `t2` to change `y` into type `float` with the least amount of code?

Comment: Do you _need_ to do this with the type _name_, or is it ok to just use the type itself? As the answer below indicate, the latter case is more straight-forward.

Comment: Yes, I need to do this with the type _name_.

Comment: Actually, no I don't need the name. My mistake. I'm editing the question and accepting the best answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
x = float(1.0)
y = int(2)

y = type(x)(y)
print(type(y))
```

**Output**

```
float
```

If you need to do this with the type *name*, just assign the type of `x` to a variable and use it as a function:

```
x = float(1.0)
y = int(2)

t = type(x)
y = t(y)
print(type(y))
```

**Output**

```
float
```

Comment: Where in your answer are you using the type *name*? none of your variables are strings

Answer (score 3):

You can first convert from the a string representing a `type` name, such as `"float"`, to the type, using the [`__builtins__`](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/builtins.html) module (more about here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11181607/2096752)):

```
def get_type_by_name(type_name):
    return getattr(__builtins__, type_name)
the_type = get_type_by_name('float')
```

Then, do the convertion:

```
y = the_type(x)
```

You can also use `eval` for that, but in general [`eval` is (harshly) discouraged](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html).

Answer (score 1):

For types that cast passed arguments when called (like `int`, `list`, etc.), just use a reference to the type, and then call it.

```
>>> x = 1.
>>> y = 2
>>> t = type(x)
>>> t(y)
2.0
>>> tup = (1,2)
>>> lst = [3,4]
>>> t2 = type(tup)
>>> t2(lst)
(3, 4)
```

Comment: I (OP) made a mistake. I don't need the type _name_.

Answer (score 0):

You already have good answers, but since programming is also about playing with stuffs, here is an alternative:

```
y.__class__(x)
```

Comment: Perhaps you mean `y = x.__class__(y)` ?