# Error when trying to get object type in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, getattr, built-in

I have a main script, which imports another python library that I've been writing.
The library contains the following command:

```
print getattr(__builtins__, "list")
```

This produces the following error when I call it from the library:

```
'dict' object has no attribute 'list'
```

But, if I copy and paste that same command into the main script it works fine. Any ideas why this isn't working?

The header of my main file looks like this:

```
#/usr/bin/env python
from sys import argv
import re, sys, os, argparse
sys.path.extend(map(os.path.abspath, ['C:/Users/xxxx/scripts/modules/']))
import general
```

The header for my "general" library is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from sys import argv
import re, sys, os, argparse

def getBuiltin(name):
    ##Convert a string into an attribute
    try:
        return getattr(__builtins__, name)
    except Exception as e:
        print "Unhandled type in function \"get_builtin\""
        print name
        print e
        exit()
```

I was calling the library like this:

```
print general.getBuiltin("list")
```

where, "getBuiltin" is the name of my function

Comment: Please provide more context to your question, it would help seeing at least the header of your main script and the library you are referring to

Comment: Yes, you need to provide a [mcve] so we can reproduce and diagnose. You wouldn’t expect your doctor could help much if you said, “It hurts when I do cartwheels.” She’d need to observe and run tests to diagnose.

Comment: Ok, I've added in a bit more context, hopefully that helps

Comment: can you dump `type(__builtins__)`? it should be a module, not a dict, so wondering if you have reassigned it somewhere.

Comment: Hi, yes, you're correct- when I  `print type(__builtins__)` in the main script, it returns `<type 'module'>`, whereas in the library, it returns `<type 'dict'>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also check this question: [Python: What's the difference between __builtin__ and __builtins__?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11181519/python-whats-the-difference-between-builtin-and-builtins)

As you can see in akent answer, **builtins** is different in main module and another module:

> Straight from the python documentation: 
>   http://docs.python.org/reference/executionmodel.html
>
> By default, when in the **main** module, **builtins** is the built-in
>   module **builtin** (note: no 's'); when in any other module,
>   **builtins** is an alias for the dictionary of the **builtin** module itself.
>
> **builtins** can be set to a user-created dictionary to create a weak form of restricted execution.
>
> CPython implementation detail: Users should not touch **builtins**; it
>   is strictly an implementation detail. Users wanting to override values
>   in the builtins namespace should import the **builtin** (no 's')
>   module and modify its attributes appropriately. The namespace for a
>   module is automatically created the first time a module is imported.
>   Note that in Python3, the module **builtin** has been renamed to
>   builtins to avoid some of this confusion.

Comment: Added `import __builtin__` and change to `getattr(__builtin__, "list")`. Thanks for the help