# How can I set the default module for parameter type links?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

In one module, I have code such as:

```
class ConfigParsers:
    def str(raw, key):
        # parse value as a string
    # other parsers

class Section(dict):
    def add_parsers(name, parsers):
        """Add a parser

        :param str name: the name of the object
        ...
        ...
```

When sphinx builds the documentation for this module using autodoc, "str" gets linked to the current pages' `ConfigParsers.str` rather than the python documention. This occurs with other built in types where the name collision is within a class, such as int and bool. I can understand the collision if the parsers were defined at the module level, however Sphinx is forming a collision even when the definition is within a class, like above.

Edit:

A work around I have just found entails using the new intersphinx mapping format, and then using `identifierusedforstdlibcode:str`, however this isn't ideal, and normally wouldn't be an issue as sphinx usually autolinks it already to an extent.

Comment: Try `:param .str name:`. That should reverse the lookup order. If it works, I'll post an answer with a link to the sphinx docs.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Unforunately, no dice. Still links to the function withing the ConfigParsers class instead of the builtin python class. I also tried `~__builtin__.str`, still failing.

Comment: You should add a tag for Python 2.7 then. I am pretty sure it's `builtins.str` in Py3: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11181519/2988730