# Python global variable with no import or global declaration

Tags: python-3.x, global-variables, python-import

I'm trying to add a couple of miscellaneous development helpers to my python project in such a way that I don't need to either `import` them or declare them `global` at the call site, just to save myself some typing.

Example usage would be something like:

```
# Somewhere, maybe src/__init__.py?
from pprint import pprint
superduperglobaleasyusenamespace.p = pprint

# A different file somewhere in my project
def whatever():
    p('hello')
```

I looked at [**builtin**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11181607/1467342) but wasn't able to get it to work. If that's the correct solution, provide example code that works in python3.

Answer (score 0):

Add this as very first line in your program:

```
__builtins__.p = pprint
```

In general, it is not recommend to modify the builtin name space. An import is just one line after all.

#### Example

```
# mod1.py

from pprint import pprint

__builtins__.p = pprint

import mod2
```

and

```
# mod2.p

print(p)
```

Now:

```
python mod1.py 
<function pprint at 0x10df28e18>
```

Comment: This does not work for me when calling `p` in a different file, I've tried the exact same thing.

Comment: Sorry. It is `__builtins__` with a `s` at the end.

Comment: Ok, this does technically work – maybe I should clarify my question a bit more. I'd like to get this to work with no explicit import between the file. I have a large project, and I want `pprint` to be available in every file, with no import, and without forcing the project to be run through a parent file (as in your example). Think php/apache auto prepend.

Comment: You program hast to start somewhere. Import and assign to `__builtins__` at the very beginning. No further imports needed.

Comment: My program has multiple entry points, none of which are the `__main__` module (for example, I export a uwsgi handler which gunicorn calls), and `__builtins__` acts like a dict when you're not in the `__main__` module.

Comment: Did you try if it works? You only need to two lines of code.

Comment: Your solution doesn't work if the module where you modify `__builtins__` isn't also `__main__`, because in any non-`__main__` module, `__builtins__` is a dict (and manipulating that dict is something I've fiddled with a bunch and hasn't worked). But yes, I did try it, in a couple configurations.