# Python mutating __builtins__ has different behaviour in REPL

Tags: python, python-idle

I'm attempting to make it so that, instead of raising a `NameError` when an undefined variable is referenced, it instead calls a function that I've defined to get the value.

**Background**

I'm a relatively advanced Python programmer, and no beginner. This question is not for practical application but for personal learning.

**What I've tried so far**

I tried to use `__builtins__.__missing__` as my function, but it only worked in shell.
This works in the Python interactive console on 3.9.1:

```
>>> __builtins__=type('', (dict,), {'__missing__': lambda *args: args[1]})(__builtins__.__dict__)
>>> print(variable)
variable
```

However, when I run it as a program, it throws `NameError: name 'variable' is not defined`

```
__builtins__=type('', (dict,), {'__missing__': lambda *args: args[1]})(__builtins__.__dict__)
print(variable)
```

**Question**

What's going on here, and how can I handle this?

Comment: This looks relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11181519/whats-the-difference-between-builtin-and-builtins

Comment: Thanks. However, changing the first `__builtins__` to `__builtin__` did not solve my issue.

Comment: The fact that this works in the repl is probably a weird quirk (I suspect the eval part of the loop just takes keeps replacing `__builtins__` in the dynamic execution). You shouldn't expect this to work in Python generally.

Comment: So, the important thing to understand is you *can* modify `__builtins__` by actually modifying the object, but *assignment of some other mapping to that name will not work because that doesn't actually mutate the built-ins namespace*

Comment: Thanks, @juanpa.arrivillaga. What can I do to give `__builtins__` a `__missing__` method then?

Comment: Also, @Barmar, I don't believe the `__builtin__` module exists in Python 3. It's been replaced with `builtins`, but changing this doesn't even work in shell.

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to accomplish by modifying `__builtins__`?

Comment: As near as I can tell, this is not an IDLE issue.  On Windows with 3.11.0a5, I get the same behavior when running in the regular interactive console or as a file.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for your response. What I'm aiming to do is to make it so that, instead of raising a `NameError` when an undefined variable is referenced, it instead calls a function that I've defined to get the value.
@TerryJanReedy confirmed with 3.9.1 in shell and in file.

Comment: You should say that in the question, and ask how to customize the handling of undefined variable references.

Comment: Should I edit the question or pose a new question?

Comment: I think you could edit this question. Say what you're trying to do, and then show this as the code you tried to use, but it didn't work.

Comment: IMO, you should abandon the idea. If you need a name to resolve to particular value, define the name.

Comment: @chepner I'm no beginner to Python, and this question is for personal learning rather than practical application.

Comment: I've found a solution involving overriding the `globals()` dictionary by using `ctypes`, but it's extremely hacky. Does a pythonic solution exist?