# Pycharm not recognising builtins

Tags: python, python-3.x, intellij-idea, pycharm

I'm using **Python 3.5.2**, **PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1.1** in **Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS**

I'm a beginner in Python and I'm trying to get this code to work.

```
a = getattr(__builtins__, 'print')
```

Actually it works fine in IDLE, but Pycharm is not recognising the builtins. Other common builtins functions like str(), int()... are woking fine.

I searched in [Pycharm support](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206585935-Pycharm-doesn-t-recognize-builtins-for-me-) for solutions.

> The "Reload" button in Settings | Python Interpreters regenerates the skeletons for binary modules, including builtins. Please try pressing it.

But its not working too. I get this in Pycharm...

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'print'
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not directly use the `__builtins__` and instead use the `builtins` module.

In the pycharm python console, the `__builtins__` acts as a dict, which in that case, you will need to retrieve `print` by `a = __builtins__['print']`.  In contrast, if you run it as a script, the `__builtins__` act as the module representation the [`builtins`ø](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html) module. In that case, you will need to do it your way using either `a = getattr(__builtins__, 'print')` or `a = __builtins__.print`.

But as I stated before, you should not directly use the `__builtins__` keyword. You should do this instead:

```
import builtins
a = builtins.print # or getatrr(builtins, 'print') which either way you prefer
```

Perhaps also check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184016/why-builtins-is-both-module-and-dict).